# ¡Hay una forma más simple de actualizar los datos de una columna en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo dos columnas una de id, en la que los valores van de 1,2,3... a 20. Y una de precio, en la que tengo que poner un valor distinto en cada uno y que estos valores se correspondan con el número de id, es decir, 1 = 10; 2 = 14...

El código que escrito es:

```
UPDATE ARTICULOS SET precio='10' WHERE id=1;
UPDATE ARTICULOS SET precio='x' WHERE id=n;
```

¿Hay una forma más simple de hacerlo o hay que hacer lo mismo con cada id?

Comment: No acabo de entender lo que pretendes. Dices que "estos valores se correspondan con el número de id"... ¿son precios calculados basados en el número de id de algun modo?  ¿O son precios únicos que pueden ser cualesquiera?  Si es esto segundo no te queda otra que actualizarlos uno a uno... pero en el primer caso con alguna fórmula o bucle se podria hacer alguna cosa distinta.

Comment: Se trata de valores aleatorios, pero ya veo que no queda otra más que hacerlo manualmente. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si son valores aleatorios podrias probar con esto:  UPDATE ARTICULOS SET precio = FLOOR(RAND())  para rellenar todos los precios de valores distintos enteros... Si los quieres dentro de un rango entonces mirate esto: https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/rand.php

Comment: He probado con UPDATE ARTICULOS SET precio = (RAND()*(200-0)) y va estupendo, me va a aligerar mucho el trabajo. Pero más bien me refería a que había usado en la columna de id el valor auto_increment y me preguntaba si se podía usar esta función a la hora de insertar los valores, algo así:  UPDATE ARTICULOS SET precio = (RAND()*(200-0)) WHERE id = x+1; . Sé que no se puede eso que acabo de escribir, pero es para dar a entender que lo que intento es que rellene aleatoriamente un valor de precio y que automáticamente, pase al siguiente y repita la acción. Perdón pero no sé explicarlo mejor!

Comment: Te entiendo pero no veo la diferencia. Es decir, si no me equivoco partimos de la base que los id ya existen. Daria igual recorrerlos a tu modo que con la consulta que has encontrado y dices que va bien, ¿no? AL final el resultado seria actualizar todos los precios de los id existentes. "Tanto monta monta tanto" que decian :-) (y ahora ya tienes un método que te funciona, no hace falta que insistas en el otro que dudo que exista dentro del propio SQL, más bien tendrias que usar PHP o algun otro lenguaje y meterlo en un bucle recorriendo los ids)

Comment: A menos que te refieras en el momento de su creación, lo cual supongo que sí puede hacerse mediante un trigger con algo asi:  `CREATE TRIGGER precio_random BEFORE INSERT ON ARTICULOS  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  SET precio =  (RAND()*(200-0)); END`... aunque no soy experto en triggers, pero si te deja crearlo deberia funcionar al insertar cualquier nuevo registro con id nuevo.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, voy a continuar del modo en el que lo estaba haciendo. Y nunca había usado un trigger, pero me lo apunto para probarlo ahora. De nuevo muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Hay que hacerlo así, una sentencia update por cada registro que se desea modificar.

Existen formas de actualizar varios registros en una sentencia update. Si por ejemplo quisieras subir el 10% a todos los precios, bastaría con hacer:

```
update articulos set precio = precio * 1.10;
```

O incluso -por ejemplo- sólo a aquellos que tienen un stock de menos de 5 unidades:

```
update articulos set precio = precio * 1.10 where stock < 5;
```

Pero no es el caso, ya que por lo que entiendo la modificación que pretendes hacer es totalmente *discreccional*: a este valor -porque sí- le quiero dar éste valor, a éste otro, otro valor distinto, sin que tenga una relación entre ambos cambios.

**Tip:** cuando me solicitan hacer un lote grande de sentencias update de este tipo, muchas veces recurro a una hoja excel o a un editor de texto para crear la lista completa de sentencias update que hay que ejecutar.